# StackoverFlowException in C#

Tags: c#

I am writing a code for setting the property in C# and getting an exception.

```
public class person
{
    public string name
    {
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {

        person p = new person();
        p.name = "Bilal";

        Console.WriteLine(p.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: please tell me error in this code.

Answer (score 14):

You have infinite recursion in your property - your setter will call itself until you get a stack overflow:

```
    set
    {
        name = value;
    }
```

Instead either use an [auto-property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) (recommended if you don't need direct access to the backing field and are not doing any other operation in your getter/setters):

```
public string name {get;set;}
```

Or use a backing field:

```
private string _name;
public string name
{
    set
    {
        _name = value;
    }
    get
    {
        return _name;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1037750 BrokenGlass is correct; follow his solution. You might also consider renaming the property to `Name`, so that you're following C# naming conventions.

Comment: Agreed - public properties should be capitalized (and camel cased where needed)

Comment: Who's recommending auto-properties and for what reasons?

Comment: @RuneFS: That's a personal recommendation of mine - I don't see any reason **not** to use an auto-property if you don't need any changes otherwise: your code is much shorter and concise, less code to maintain and potential pitfalls like this avoided.

Comment: I asked out of curiosity since I generally avoid auto props. I never really got the idea of auto props. mostly seems as a "Approved" version of public fields. Sure if you make the setter private it's different but then you could often make the field read only which is an even stronger contract. Not trying to make it a "you/me are wrong, you/me is right" it simple curiosity

Answer (score 5):

Your property name and your field name are the same ("name"). Capitalize the property name.

Or just switch to an auto-prop:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: There's no field only a property

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
  private string _name;
  public string Name
    {
        set
        {
            _name = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
    }
```

To avoid the problem and to be clear about what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
string name;
public string Name
    {
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
    }
```